# How is best method to manage SEO parameters for Dynamic Component Presentations in Tridion?

Tags: content-delivery

I have sort of implementation where i have single page and rendering Dynamic data on same page at runtime, every time different data is rendered (say News Article), so does diff SEO parameters. But usually SEO data attached to page parameters in static content.
So what would be the best way to achieve this in Tridion?

Comment: In Tridion is easy--the SEO details should live with your articles. Your question is really about *delivery*. So... tell us about your delivery setup. :-)

Answer (score 7):

The best way depends on many factors. For example:

- how proficient are the content editors
- what are the localization requirements
- what are the editorial security constraints (who needs to/can publish what)
- what is the application architecture (how you're rendering items: dd4t/xml, DWT/razor, etc)
- Is there a need for SiteEdit/XPM integration
- Is there a need for Smart Target integration

and etc.

Your options are:

- store it on a page where the page is published dynamically to DB
- store it in a separate SEO component attached to the page's metadata.
- store it on the News (or your content) component as additional Content fields or Meta fields.

The "best way" is something that needs to be assessed by your architects and clients, and not something that should be recommended via a brief Q&A in a forum.

Answer (score 4):

As Nickoli says, this is completely dependent on your implementation and any constraints that you may face.

If you are not concerned about the the SEO details being the same on all news articles, then you can continue to use the page parameters.

If you want the SEO details to be specific to each news article then you will need to implement this dynamically.  The SEO details will need to be associated with the news Component - probably either within the Metadata of the Component or as a linked Component.

I presume that the SEO details are just plain text `keywords` and `description`.  To surface this information you then have two choices:

1. Render the keywords and description as a Dynamic Component Presentation, or
2. Query the Broker database (assuming that you use a licensed Broker database) for the text strings. (Either using the API or Content Delivery webservice)

Again, there are many ways that you could get to, and render, each of these.  I have done this in the past using a .NET user control that then writes these 'up' to properties in a .NET master page.  This is very much dependent on your implementation though.